# Does the C++ standard require a binary machine?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I find in the standard:

> The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system

But my understanding is that this is not a requirement that C++ must be implemented on machines that are based on base 2 in hardware; in other words, this seems to be only a requirement for what the programmer shall see.

Does the C++ standard require a binary CPU, or could a valid C++ implementation be implemented on ternary or decimal machines?

---

<sup>tiny background info: in history, there have already been computers with decimals, ternaries, or computers where a C++byte would be 36 bits long (PDP-10)</sup>

Comment: It's hard to see how e.g. bitwise operators would work on a non-binary architecture, unless you have some kind of binary virtual machine in between, in which case the underlying architecture is moot.

Comment: That passage in the standard seems pretty clear to me.  It requires a machine capable of making binary representations of numbers.  In other words, a typical modern digital computer, or at least one that can emulate binary numbers.

Comment: `N3337 3.9.1 Fundamental types` `Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type. The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system. [ Example: this International Standard permits 2's complement, 1's complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types. —end example ]` I guess this might come under "as if" though.

Comment: Also `N3337 4.7 Integral conversions` `If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two's complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although never directly stated in the standard, there's an "as if" rule that applies to essentially all requirements in the C++ (and C) standard.

In other words, you're allowed to break any rule you want to, as long as you produce the same externally observable effects as if you'd followed the rule as stated. Although not stated in the standards themselves, this rule *is* explicitly stated in the [Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) for the C standard. As far as I know, there's no matching rationale for the C++ standard, but the two are closely enough related that I see little problem in applying the rule to both.

Comment: I believe there is a foot-note that mentions "as-if" under 1.9.1.

Comment: I don't know about earlier standards, but in C++11 § 1.9/1 this is stated directly: `The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This International Standard places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.`